# Basic authentication in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, login-control

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.fpl.basicauth, PID: 2485
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method TextFieldClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText with id 'etuserID'
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I've got this error when running the basic authentication on android studio.